# Angular 8 : Check array contains value of string in component view not work in IE

Tags: arrays, angular, internet-explorer

I have angular 8 application. I want to check if array contains the given string in component view. I have used `Array.includes` which work in chrome but IE gives error *Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'*

Component view Look like :

```
<div [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': invalidProps?.includes('errorprop')}"> 
  Error message 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add line below in the **polyfills.ts** file.

```
import 'core-js/es6/array';
```

It may help you to fix your error.

Comment: Does not worked. Getting ```Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/array'``` error

Comment: Generally, that polyfill located in an es6 or es7 directory. But the 'array' polyfill is the same. It looks like adding the 'array' polyfill solved your issue. I suggest you mark the helpful suggestion as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I added below line to polyfills.ts file and it working

`import "core-js/es/array";`

Thanks for hint.